# Delete empty spaces in a String without removing linebreaks

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a list of strings in a `txt` file

```
string1,
string2,
string3,
string4,
```

I want to delete `string3`

`txtData = txtData.replace("string3,", "");`

```
string1,
string2,

string4,
```

I don't want that empty space there so I do this

`txtData = txtData.replace("\n", "");`

but that does this instead

`string1,string2,string4`

I need this

```
string1,
string2,
string4,
```

how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the two things you tried:

```
txtData = txtData.replace("string3,\n", "");
```

If you also want this to work if `string3,`is at the end of the file and may or may not be followed by a newline:

```
txtData = txtData.replaceAll("(?m)string3,$", "");
```

That's a regular expression that matches 'end of line' (`$` means: 'end of line', if in multiline mode. `(?m)` turns on multiline mode).

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions for this purpose:

```java
String str =
        "string1,\n" +
        "string2,\n" +
        "string3,\n" +
        "string4,";

// remove literal "string3," and trailing
// whitespace characters after it, if present
String str2 = str.replaceAll("string3,\\s*","");

System.out.println(str2);
```

Output:

```
string1,
string2,
string4,
```